# How do I get the local machine name in C#?

Tags: c#, dns, hostname

How do I get the local machine name?

Comment: Duplicate Question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459034/get-computer-name-from-within-a-windows-service)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the computer name in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768198/how-do-i-get-the-computer-name-in-net)

Answer (score 167, accepted):

[System.Environment.MachineName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename.aspx)

It works unless a [machine name has more than 15 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088346/environment-machinename-is-cropped-to-15-characters?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Sorry :) These little questions are kind of a turkey shoot. I kind of assumed there'd be 4 answers by the time I posted.

Comment: Just a note, in .NET Standard on Android this seems to return "localhost"

Answer (score 55):

From
[source](http://blog.xploiter.com/2008/09/17/get-your-local-machinecomputer-name-in-c/)

Four ways to get your local network/machine name:

```
string name = Environment.MachineName;
string name = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
string name = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.ComputerName;
string name = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME");
```

More information at:
[Difference between SystemInformation.ComputerName, Environment.MachineName, and Net.Dns.GetHostName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233217/difference-between-systeminformation-computername-environment-machinename-and-n)

Answer (score 48):

You should be able to use `System.Environment.MachineName` for this.  It is a property that returns a string containing the netBIOS name of the computer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename.aspx

Answer (score 21):

If you want the FQDN (fully qualified domain name) of the local computer, you can use

`System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").HostName`

The other methods will only return the local name, without any domain specific info. For instance, for the computer `myComp.myDomain.com`, the previous methods will return `myComp`, whereas the `GetHostEntry` method will return `myComp.myDomain.com`

Comment: In computer settings there's a section for Computer Name and Full Computer Name--this is the only way I've found for getting the Full Computer Name when everyone else just gives the Computer Name. Thank you!

Comment: hmm, just gives `localhost` for me, not `FQDN`.

Comment: `localhost` in not needed, you can just provide an empty string: `Dns.GetHostEntry("").HostName`.

Answer (score 0):

My computer name is more than 15 chars, so i use hostname.exe to get full length name:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "c:/windows/system32/hostname.exe";
proc.Start();
var hostName = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
```