# How to get IPAddress using Environment.MachineName?

Tags: c#, .net

Below code can get us IPAddress using `Environment.MachineName` but `Environment.MachineName` can return maximum upto `15` characters, what if the value is more than `15` characters?

```
string IP_Address = Dns.GetHostByName(Environment.MachineName).AddressList[0].toString();
```

Comment: Use an empty string instead (it returns local computer information). Also note that you shouldn't pick first entry...it may return multiple addresses (both for physical networks and for logical ones).

Comment: I din get what you are saying repetti, can you please write the statement you are talking about?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Dns.GetHostName(). See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostname(v=vs.110).aspx

> System.Net.Dns.GetHostName() returns the computer's TCP/IP based
>   hostname. By adding a domain suffix to the hostname you can resolve
>   your computer's IP address across LANs / on the internet.

**Source:** [Difference between SystemInformation.ComputerName, Environment.MachineName, and Net.Dns.GetHostName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233217/difference-between-systeminformation-computername-environment-machinename-and)

You can find the domain suffix using this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.dnssuffix(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But attackers can spoof the DNS Host name so Dns.GetHostName() is not reliable. Is there any other better way?

Comment: I am afraid you probably have to validate the legitimacy of the DNS Host name. Perhaps this will help you: https://sujithin.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/misused-authentication-using-gethostname-asp-net/