# get part of a Computers name

Tags: c#

How can I get a part of a system's name? For instance if the computer name contains `SERVER` then do something, and if it includes `CLIENT` then do something else.

The names I an working with are similar to `SERVER000455`. The numerical values change all the time but the `SERVER` part is the same.

Getting the name is easy (`SystemInformation.ComputerName`), but that wasn't my question. My question was getting just the first part of the name. The `string[]` and `split` doesn't seem to work since it's not an array. I just need to get the prefix of the PC name and drop the numerical bit.

Comment: Can we see the error that you get?

Comment: wow, thanks Jonesy for nothing. getting the name is easy
    SystemInformation.ComputerName
that wasn't my question, my question was getting just the first part of the name. the srting[] and split doesn't seem to work since it's not an array. I just need to get the prefix of the PC name and drop the numerical bit

Comment: See this question: [how do I get the local machine name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662282/how-do-i-get-the-local-machine-name)

Comment: Well, then, why did you need to ask the question?

Comment: @ShaneTheTech my smartass-ness aside, it was not the answer you wanted, but the answer you needed sir.

Comment: This question does have a big problem. You don't show what you tried. Thus people got confused, and didn't know what you were even trying to do.

Comment: I guess I could have explained better, but the basic question was how to get PART of a computers name, not the name itself. I thought giving the basic examples of this is the names in general IE: SERVER000455 and CLIENT000455, but all i needed was the name not the numerical values.

Comment: I do thank everyone on this site for assisting me on this learning process with C# and I hope that soon I will be able to help others as well in other areas. I am learning from a book and in VS 2012....it's not been so easy as of yet but I am getting there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I thought the main question was the computer name.  But you want:

```
String machinename = System.Environment.MachineName;

if(machinename.ToUpper().Contains("SERVER"))
{

}
else if (machinename.ToUpper().Contains("CLIENT"))
{

}
```

Comment: yes that was the question, thank you. If you have a second what is the purpose of the ToUpper?

Comment: if the machine name is server10 it won't match "SERVER", ToUpper() uppercases all the letters.  Thus you know case won't be an issue in the comparison

Comment: i would ask that if my answer helped you you checkmark it

Comment: I had to wait 5 minutes before it would allow me

Comment: a tip of the hat to you

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Environment.MachineName.ToUpper().Contains("SERVER"))
{
    // etc.
}
```