# c# get host server name for web app

Tags: c#, web-applications

I am building a web application and I want to be able to get the name of the server that the application is running on.

I've seen a few examples that suggest using `System.Environment.MachineName` but it wasn't clear to me if this would retrieve the server name or the computer name of the user accessing the application. Can someone clear this up for me?

Thanks

Comment: What's an example of the sort of name you want returned?  The Windows machine name?  Or the DNS host name?  Or something else?

Comment: Its the machine name i'm after. The one you can see if you go to Control Panel > System > Computer name

Comment: Your web code runs on the server, so it returns the name of the server the web application is running on.

Comment: Your code should work fine. Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx .It gets the NetBIOS name. It also is confirmed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662282/how-do-i-get-the-local-machine-name .This actually does the same thing as typing hostname to the command prompt.