# Environment.MachineName is cropped to 15 characters

Tags: c#

There is a property in .NET System.Environment.MachineName which read the name of a computer cropped up to the 15 characters because of compatibility with Windows 98.

How can I get full (not cropped) name?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/662282/15498) and especially the *alternate* answers explore some other options.

Comment: have you tried `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME")`?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, yes I tried. Same to me. 15 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use WMI to get the name of the system

```
using System.Management;

try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                "SELECT Name FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Win32_ComputerSystem instance");
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", queryObj["Name"]);
            }
        }
        catch (ManagementException e)
        {
            // exception handling
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using *interop*

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...

[DllImport("KERNEL32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, BestFitMapping = false)]
private extern static int GetComputerName(
  [Out]StringBuilder nameBuffer, 
  ref int bufferSize);
...

int size = 0; // do not try to return any name, but its actual size only

// What's actual size of the machine name?
GetComputerName(null, ref size);

// Obtaining the machine name 
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(size);
GetComputerName(buffer, ref size);

string name = buffer.ToString();
```

Comment: Same problem to me. Size is limited to 15