# Designated Machine Name after Change

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10

I know, in .NET, I can get the current computer name with `Environment.MachineName`. When using Win+R `ms-settings:about` or something equivalent to change the computer name, how can I get the *designated* computer name that will be used after restart?

Comment: I would guess it's stored in the registry, but I would also guess that where in the registry is liable to be version dependent (i.e. any update to windows would possibly change it).  Why do you need this information, there may be a better (and supported) way to do what you want.

Comment: I don't see how this question is about programming. It seems like it's about Windows OS to me.

Comment: How is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662282/how-do-i-get-the-local-machine-name-in-c then a question is about programming?

Comment: I have to ask.  Why?

Comment: In our corporation, all computer names have to follow some pattern. Because none of the solutions to change the computer name worked, on a wrong pattern, the program prompts the users to change the machine name themselves, opening the About page. I want to check the pattern of the designated name again.

Comment: I would have personally locked them out of changing the name and written an application that allows them to change it, but also enforces a naming convention.  But, either way see below for the info you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the future value of the MachineName property at the following registry key...

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName
```