# how to get pc name or device name by using MVC or javascript or c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC4 to build report. Now I have one problem want to ask you.
I will build this project and publish it into IIS. Because of customer requirement, they need to control how many of user have logged in to see web report and what they want to see are : PC Name or Device Name IP Address and Win User.Among of those points, there is 1 important point ( PC Name or Device Name). I don't know how to get that info. so does anybody know how to get pc name or device name by using MVC or javascript or c#?

Comment: For the PC Name see [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768198/how-do-i-get-the-computer-name-in-net)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read the client's machine/computer name from the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922476/how-can-i-read-the-clients-machine-computer-name-from-the-browser)

Comment: MVC is a design pattern. A design pattern cannot determine your machine name. You should ask two separate questions: How to get machine name using JavaScript? and How to get machine name using C#? However, I am sure these questions exist already.