# Detect machine change

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing a small tool that is going to be distributed via executable.
The first time it is executed I want a tutorial to be displayed. As users are supposed to copy/paste the tool to theirs coworkers it would be nice if I detect that the machine has been changed and display the tutorial again for the new user.

If I could identify the machine ID somehow I could store it (as a setting for example) and compare it at startup in order to display or not the tutorial.

Is there a way to identify somehow the current machine?

Comment: Are you able to create an installer? would be much easier and less error prone (what if a user wants to copy to a second computer?)

Comment: This question seems quite similar in essence to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768198/how-do-i-get-the-computer-name-in-net

Comment: The enviroment of the deployment is supossed to have restricted rights. Being portable is a feature in order to avoid call the IT guy to log as admin and install it.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at LocalStorage - which basically stores information per user. Write a small file on startup und check for it every time. If it's there, you know the user otherwise he is new.

Answer (score 0):

The `Process` Class has a property which indicates the machine name.

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().MachineName
```

**Edit**

Or get the machine name from `System.Environment.MachineName`

*(thanks to Andreas Niedermair for mentioning it)*

Comment: Isn't this the same as `Environment.MachineName`? How would you ensure that the `MachinName` is unique? What do you do when the user changes the name via the system-settings?

Comment: Not sure what is going wrong but I'm getting a dumb '.' (a simple point) from that property. But it works using `System.Environment.MachineName`

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair If I needed to identify a unique machine, I'd get its MAC address, but he simply wanted to get the machine name. Maybe someone has to replace their machine. In this case, it could be unwanted to display the tutorial again.

Comment: @Chrisi It all depends on the definition of "machine change": What if the network card, disk, windows-setup, ... gets replaced. Is it still the same machine? full ack!