# Using PC name by default

Tags: vb.net, chat

I finished my Chat over LAN project and everything work great,
but i have problem here,I don't want users put their name every time they want to send msgs over LAN, I want the program use the PC name by default, so in chat section the PC name will appear automatically, Can someone help me in this!

& this is my code

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices
Imports System.Net

Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports MSTSCLib
Public Class frmMain

    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
#Region " Windows Form Designer generated code "

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        'This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        'Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call

    End Sub

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing Then
            If Not (components Is Nothing) Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        End If
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    Friend WithEvents TreeView1 As System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
    Friend WithEvents txtPCName As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    Friend WithEvents txtSend As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    Friend WithEvents CmdSend As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Friend WithEvents ImageList1 As System.Windows.Forms.ImageList
    Friend WithEvents txtPCIPadd As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    Friend WithEvents Label3 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents Timer1 As System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    Friend WithEvents txtUsername As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    Friend WithEvents Label4 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents Label5 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents txtConversation As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    Friend WithEvents txttempmsg As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    Friend WithEvents Label2 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
        Dim resources As System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager = New System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(GetType(frmMain))
        Me.CmdSend = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.TreeView1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TreeView()
        Me.ImageList1 = New System.Windows.Forms.ImageList(Me.components)
        Me.txtPCName = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.txtSend = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.txtPCIPadd = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.Label2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.Label3 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.Timer1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer(Me.components)
        Me.txtUsername = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.Label4 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.Label5 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.txtConversation = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.txttempmsg = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'CmdSend
        '
        Me.CmdSend.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.CmdSend.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(404, 265)
        Me.CmdSend.Name = "CmdSend"
        Me.CmdSend.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 52)
        Me.CmdSend.TabIndex = 0
        Me.CmdSend.Text = "&Send"
        '
        'TreeView1
        '
        Me.TreeView1.ImageIndex = 0
        Me.TreeView1.ImageList = Me.ImageList1
        Me.TreeView1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(291, 10)
        Me.TreeView1.Name = "TreeView1"
        Me.TreeView1.SelectedImageIndex = 0
        Me.TreeView1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(168, 234)
        Me.TreeView1.TabIndex = 1
        '
        'ImageList1
        '
        Me.ImageList1.ImageStream = CType(resources.GetObject("ImageList1.ImageStream"), System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)
        Me.ImageList1.TransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent
        Me.ImageList1.Images.SetKeyName(0, "")
        '
        'txtPCName
        '
        Me.txtPCName.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(108, 34)
        Me.txtPCName.Name = "txtPCName"
        Me.txtPCName.ReadOnly = True
        Me.txtPCName.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(136, 20)
        Me.txtPCName.TabIndex = 2
        '
        'txtSend
        '
        Me.txtSend.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 266)
        Me.txtSend.Multiline = True
        Me.txtSend.Name = "txtSend"
        Me.txtSend.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Both
        Me.txtSend.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(386, 52)
        Me.txtSend.TabIndex = 3
        '
        'txtPCIPadd
        '
        Me.txtPCIPadd.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(108, 58)
        Me.txtPCIPadd.Name = "txtPCIPadd"
        Me.txtPCIPadd.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(136, 20)
        Me.txtPCIPadd.TabIndex = 6
        '
        'Label2
        '
        Me.Label2.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label2.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.Label2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(13, 59)
        Me.Label2.Name = "Label2"
        Me.Label2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(71, 15)
        Me.Label2.TabIndex = 7
        Me.Label2.Text = "IP Address :"
        '
        'Label3
        '
        Me.Label3.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label3.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.Label3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 247)
        Me.Label3.Name = "Label3"
        Me.Label3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(58, 15)
        Me.Label3.TabIndex = 9
        Me.Label3.Text = "Message"
        '
        'Timer1
        '
        '
        'txtUsername
        '
        Me.txtUsername.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(108, 10)
        Me.txtUsername.Name = "txtUsername"
        Me.txtUsername.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(136, 20)
        Me.txtUsername.TabIndex = 10
        '
        'Label4
        '
        Me.Label4.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label4.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.Label4.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(13, 14)
        Me.Label4.Name = "Label4"
        Me.Label4.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(70, 15)
        Me.Label4.TabIndex = 11
        Me.Label4.Text = "Your name:"
        '
        'Label5
        '
        Me.Label5.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label5.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.Label5.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(13, 35)
        Me.Label5.Name = "Label5"
        Me.Label5.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(44, 15)
        Me.Label5.TabIndex = 12
        Me.Label5.Text = "Buddy:"
        '
        'txtConversation
        '
        Me.txtConversation.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
        Me.txtConversation.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(15, 84)
        Me.txtConversation.Multiline = True
        Me.txtConversation.Name = "txtConversation"
        Me.txtConversation.ReadOnly = True
        Me.txtConversation.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Both
        Me.txtConversation.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(270, 160)
        Me.txtConversation.TabIndex = 14
        '
        'txttempmsg
        '
        Me.txttempmsg.Enabled = False
        Me.txttempmsg.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 342)
        Me.txttempmsg.Multiline = True
        Me.txttempmsg.Name = "txttempmsg"
        Me.txttempmsg.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(212, 23)
        Me.txttempmsg.TabIndex = 15
        Me.txttempmsg.Visible = False
        '
        'frmMain
        '
        Me.AutoScaleBaseSize = New System.Drawing.Size(5, 13)
        Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonFace
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(471, 329)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.txttempmsg)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.txtConversation)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label5)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label4)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.txtUsername)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label3)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label2)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.txtPCIPadd)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.txtSend)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.txtPCName)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.TreeView1)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.CmdSend)
        Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D
        Me.Icon = CType(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon"), System.Drawing.Icon)
        Me.Name = "frmMain"
        Me.Text = "KiWi Messenger"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.PerformLayout()

    End Sub

#End Region
    Dim listerner As New TcpListener(44444)
    Dim client As TcpClient
    Dim client2 As TcpClient
    Dim message As String = ""
    Dim tts As Object
    Dim Sound As New System.Media.SoundPlayer()


    Private Sub frmMain_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        listerner.Stop()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'TextBox1.Selectionstart = TextBox1.TextLength
        'TextBox1.ScrollToCaret()


        Dim childEntry As DirectoryEntry
        Dim ParentEntry As New DirectoryEntry()
        Try
            ParentEntry.Path = "WinNT:"
            For Each childEntry In ParentEntry.Children
                Dim newNode As New TreeNode(childEntry.Name)
                Select Case childEntry.SchemaClassName
                    Case "Domain"
                        Dim ParentDomain As New TreeNode(childEntry.Name)
                        TreeView1.Nodes.AddRange(New TreeNode() {ParentDomain})

                        Dim SubChildEntry As DirectoryEntry
                        Dim SubParentEntry As New DirectoryEntry()
                        SubParentEntry.Path = "WinNT://" & childEntry.Name
                        For Each SubChildEntry In SubParentEntry.Children
                            Dim newNode1 As New TreeNode(SubChildEntry.Name)
                            Select Case SubChildEntry.SchemaClassName
                                Case "Computer"
                                    ParentDomain.Nodes.Add(newNode1)
                            End Select
                        Next
                End Select
            Next
        Catch Excep As Exception
            MsgBox("Error While Reading Directories")
        Finally
            ParentEntry = Nothing
        End Try

        listerner.Start()
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        Timer1.Start()


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CmdSend.Click
        ' Shell("net send " & txtcomputer.Text & " " & txtmessage.Text)

        Try
            If txtPCIPadd.Text = "" Or txtUsername.Text = "" Or txtSend.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("Sorry Incomplete data")
            Else
                client = New TcpClient(txtPCIPadd.Text, 44444)
                Dim writer As New StreamWriter(client.GetStream())

                txttempmsg.Text = (txtSend.Text)
                writer.Write(txtUsername.Text + " says: " + txtSend.Text)
                txtConversation.Text = (txtConversation.Text + txtUsername.Text + " says: " + txttempmsg.Text + vbCrLf)
                'txtmsg.Text="You:" + txtmessage.Text)
                writer.Flush()
                txtSend.Text = ""
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect
        txtPCName.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text
        txtPCIPadd.Text = GetIPAddress(txtPCName.Text)
    End Sub

    Function GetIPAddress(ByVal CompName As String) As String
        Dim oAddr As System.Net.IPAddress
        Dim sAddr As String
        Try
            With System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(CompName)

                oAddr = New System.Net.IPAddress(.AddressList(0).Address)
                sAddr = oAddr.ToString
            End With

            GetIPAddress = sAddr
        Catch Excep As Exception
            MsgBox(Excep.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Lan Messenger")
        Finally

        End Try
    End Function

    Private Sub CmdPing_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Shell("PING " & txtPCIPadd.Text)
    End Sub


    'Shell("net send ALL " & txtmessage.Text)

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Try
            If listerner.Pending = True Then
                message = ""
                client = listerner.AcceptTcpClient
                Dim reader As New StreamReader(client.GetStream())
                While reader.Peek > -1
                    message = message + Convert.ToChar(reader.Read()).ToString
                End While
                Me.Focus()
                txtConversation.Text = (txtConversation.Text + message + vbCrLf)
                txtConversation.SelectionStart = txtConversation.TextLength
                txtConversation.ScrollToCaret()

                'txtmsg.Text="You:" + txtmessage.Text)

                My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.alert, AudioPlayMode.Background)
                Sound.Load()
                Sound.Play()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Function c() As String
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function


    Private Sub txtUsername_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtUsername.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please put only relevant part of code. Have  you tried some searching? Some possibilities are in (this answer)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768198/how-do-i-get-the-computer-name-in-net].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the computer's name by using

```
System.Environment.MachineName
```

...of which you can assign to a variable, which in your instance would be:

```
txtUsername.Text = System.Environment.MachineName
```

Alternatively if you like doing things the long-winded way, you can use the WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation), as per se:

```
Dim details() As String = {"Name"}
Dim wmiItems As Dictionary(Of String, String)
wmiItems = WMI.GetWMISettingsDictionary("Win32_ComputerSystem", details)
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In wmiItems
    txtUsername.Text = kvp.Value
Next
```

You can also get other system information in the same way, such as the make and model; [refer to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this.
To use WMI you must refer to the `System.Management` library, place the following at the top of the code file:

```
Imports System.Management
```