# Building multiple executables with different parameters

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to build several executables of the same project that only differ slightly in some parameters?

I have several servers my code will be deployed to but no dynamic way to identify them beforehand, that makes me think I need pre-packed configurations for each server that have the same logic but different hyperparameters. These only serve to identify the output later on and remain unchanged, so I want to resort to just shipping executables without config files for simplification.

Comment: if the output is just dependent on server name, why not just look up server name and include in output? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768198/how-do-i-get-the-computer-name-in-net

Comment: That's a possibility, yes. But the process that the application supports is a scheduled routine several times a month that should go without human interference as much as possible. Seeing as I don't know which server names are involved, just where the file transfer is coming from, I would need to manually update the correct name.

Comment: How about a command line parameter that passes in the necessary information? Create a batch file on each server with the necessary information passed into the executable. That way you set up the config once, then you have one exe doing different things on different servers.