# How To Display Computer Name in razor component

Tags: c#, razor, environment-variables, blazor-webassembly, computer-name

I try to display my computer name in razor component with this way:

```
@page "/home"

@using System;
@using System.Net;

<h2>The Computer name is: @PcName</h2>
        
 @code
{
  string PcName = Environment.MachineName.ToString();
}
```

But the output is The Computer name is:emscripten.
How can i display my computer name in razor component.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768198/how-do-i-get-the-computer-name-in-net

Comment: I've already seen that question but the out put is not correct instead of Computer name it is displaying emscripten.

Comment: The code inside @code{} runs on client machine and for security reasons the browser won't allow client side code to access machine details.

Comment: What can i do to access it in client?