# C# Application - Get Hostname + IPAddress from raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application which was currently only being used on Windows machines. Now want to use it also in raspberry PI with linux distributions (raspbian).

My problem is this line:

```
string ComputerName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]).HostName;
```

This was giving my Active Directy PC full name. Now on the PI I would like to have something like `IPAddress + Hostname`. But I don´t know how to get those values from a C# application.

Any help would be appreciated, tnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For HostName: `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"];`

For IPAddress :  `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];` (See also [How to Get IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907195/how-to-get-ip-address))

You can see list of `ServerVariables` at [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524602(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`is only set if the request goes through a proxy.

Comment: Yes you are right, that is why I added https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907195/how-to-get-ip-address to my answer

Comment: The *Hostname* bit didn't work for me (or perhaps I'm judging wrongly what the hostname actually is). Instead of giving my PI Hostname (which is APLGRT10001) it gives me the IP.

Comment: How about if you try this `System.Net.Dns.GetHostByAddress(Request.ServerVariables.Item("REMOTE_HOST")).HostName` ?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. It says `GetHostByAddress` is obsolete, to change it to `GetHostEntry`. `GetHostEntry` wasn't working on the PI's, so that's why I was searching an alternative. (it would give me a Socket.Exception: No Such host is known)

Comment: Could you please try all options that mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1768219/5519709, I assume one of them will work :)

Comment: Is rDNS lookup working on your RaspberryPi? Try it for example with `nslookup someip` in the shell.

Comment: @SelimYildiz The example you gave me return the server's name, not  the clients (the PI's).

Comment: @SelimYildiz I don't have the nslookup package installed on my PI's. Do I need it to get the hostname? Is there no other way? (I would have to update a lot of PI's, sigh)

Comment: @SelimYildiz you don't need nslookup for rDNS lookups to work, it is one of the possibilities to check if it works. `dig -x ipaddress` would be another possibility to check it.