# How Can I Access The Client Machine In Outlook Web Addin Developed In The Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

- I have developed a web add-in for the outlook.
- Addin is developed using the Blazor app.
- Blazor app is using one class library which is developed in .NET 2.0.
- The balzor web app is hosted on the server.
- But .NET standard class library is generating runtime DB files on specified path.Because it's using `Sqlite.InterOp` & `System.Data.Sqlite` NuGets. Which are the reason to generate those DB files runtime.
- As the blazor app hosted on the server, The DB files will be generated on the server machine instead of client machine. **I know it's weird thing. But it's a requirement to have those DB files on the client machine.**

So, Is there any way to generate those files runtime on the client machine.

Answer (score 0):

The best what you could do is to use the Blazor client side solution (WebAssembly). Read more about that in the [Creating A Step-By-Step End-To-End Database Client-Side (WebAssembly) Blazor Application (Updated to .Net 6)](https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/6) article.

The client-side part is very limited comparing the server-side for security reasons. You still can't access the file system on the client side, the application must be running in a sandbox.

Also for security reasons the browser won't allow client side code to access machine details. So, the solution described in the [How do I get the computer name in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768198/how-do-i-get-the-computer-name-in-net) thread may not work.